# Checking if the user entered an int - C

Tags: c, loops, input, while-loop, scanf

I need to check if the user entered a integer in a scanf() (in C). I have this code:

```
do {
    srs = scanf("%d", &x);
} while (!srs);
```

If I enter a number it works and continues with the program, but if I enter a char, it just asks me for input again. Though, if then of this I enter a correct integer, it don't break the loop.

Comment: scanf returns the number of variables assigned, which is why your loop continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't enter the number first, it leaves the non-numeric character on the input stream for the next call to pick up. So you get in an infinite loop.

You should be using `fgets` to read a whole line of input, then `sscanf` on that input line.

```
do {
    char line[512];
    fgets(line,512,stdin);
    srs = sscanf(line,"%d", &x);
} while (!srs);
```

Comment: sscanf reads the number from a string [the line you filled with fgets] instead of directly from the keyboard.